# edgecolors - how to color the border of markers

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(0.028, 0.008, marker='_', s=300, lw = 4, color='blue', edgecolors= 'black', clip_on=False, zorder = 2)
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image: result]

When I write `color = 'none'`, I get a white plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the marker you are using does not have an edge.
Indeed if you change the marker to

```
ax.scatter(0.028, 0.008, marker='o', s=300, lw = 4, color='blue', edgecolors= 'black', clip_on=False, zorder = 2)
```

You correctly get the output

[image]